# Arduino + дисплей

Tags: arduino, экран

Собираю для машины небольшой бортовой компьютер на arduino и появилась проблема — нужно реализовать понятие "виртуальных экранов".

Т.е. у меня условно есть три экрана, на первом отображаются данные с термодатчиков, на втором, например, скорость, на третьем — давление.

Смена экранов должна происходить по нажатию кнопки. Я делал через пин прерывания, то работает не правильно — прерывание врезается в цикл.

Как правильнее это реализовать или хотя бы в какую сторону рыть, потому что не понимаю даже какой запрос гуглить. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прерывание с кнопки циклически обновляет переменную, в которой записан "номер" текущего экрана. В прерывании таймера вы смотрите на эту переменную и отрисовываете нужный экран. В основном потоке, например, идет сбор данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обработчике прерывания устанавливается флаг прерывания, например переменная `bool buttonPressed`.

В основном цикле `loop` проверяется, изменился ли флаг, и если да, то сменяется экран.

Так обрабатываются прерывания в подобных случаях.